# Sorting a table by clicking the table head column in Django Web

Tags: python, mysql, django, twitter-bootstrap, web

So I have a website in django.
I have a table with a few colums like ServerName,IP etc..
I would like to have the header of the columns to sort the entire column.
For example when I click the ServerName column it will order all the items by ABC order of the ServerName.

I have heard of django-sorting-bootstrap but the guide seem complicated.
Is there any easier or good guide to do that?
the idea is to click with the arrow on the head and it will sort it out (It will be like a link).

index.html table-

```
<div class="container">

    <br>
    <center><h1>DevOps Server List</h1></center>
    <br>
    <form method='GET' action=''>
        <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search Item'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Search' />
    </form>
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>

      <tr>
        <th> Server Name </th>
        <th> Owner </th>
        <th> Project </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        <th> IP Address </th>
        <th> ILO </th>
        <th> Rack </th>
        <th> Status </th>
        <th>  </th>


    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

                {% for server in posts %}

        <tr>
          <div class ="server">
            <td>{{ server.ServerName }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.Owner }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.Project }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.Description }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.IP }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.ILO }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.Rack }}</td>
            <td>{{ server.Status }}</td>

            <td>


                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#delete-server-{{server.id}}" data-target="#Del{{server.id}}">Delete <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" </span></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteItem">Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" </span></button>
                        <div id ="Del{{server.id}}" class="modal fade" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" id="delete-server-{{server.id}}">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                            <h6>Are you sure you want to delete {{ server.ServerName }}?</h6>

                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" value="Confirm delete"/>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>


                        </div>
            </div>
            </td>
                </div>
        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</h5>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a javascript plugin to do the sorting on the client side.

For example : https://datatables.net/ do the trick very nicely.

You would need javascript to do that anyway - django will only to the server side.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function () {
  $('#ServerList').DataTable();
 } );
 </script>

I added it to my website and also added the website in the head:
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

But it didn't work.. anything else needed? :(

Comment: That should work I guess you'd need to show the full page ? Have you put the <script> at the end of the <head> ?

Comment: @EilonA  did you able to implements the same ?